# How to tackle missing data codes in a dataframe if they are text in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I am pretty new to python, so please do forgive me for stupid questions and the crudeness of my code.

I am reading in data from a provided data set (in .dta format), and sadly the missing errors seem to be coming out as text, and the other data points are numeric. I read the data in as:

```
w2bio = pd.read_stata(r'./Data/w2_nurse.dta',
                    columns=['idauniq', 'hscrp', 'cfib'                     
                             ])
```

Which gave me a data frame with a unique id, and two variables (that are catagorical containing numeric values with decimal places and strings):

```
w2bio.dtypes

Out[212]: 
idauniq    category
hscrp      category
cfib       category
dtype: object

w2bio['cfib'].value_counts
Out[214]: 
<bound method IndexOpsMixin.value_counts of 0                          3.2
1                          3.1
2                          2.9
3                          3.7
4                          3.3
         
7661                       2.9
7662                       2.9
7663                       3.4
7664    Blood sample not taken
7665                       3.2
Name: cfib, Length: 7666, dtype: category
Categories (68, object): ['Blood sample not taken' < 'Sample leaked' < 'Sample unusable (for other reason)' < 'Period between collection and receipt in the ... ... 7.7 < 7.8 < 8.5 < 8.9]>
```

I have tried the following

```
w2bio['cfib'] = w2bio['cfib'].cat.codes
```

Which then allow me to convert the variable in to a float, which is what it should be (as the variable is continous). However, returning the text missing codes to their respective catagorical code also changes the numerical values to their order in the list making them useless.

How can I select only the rows that have the text to change that? or read in the stata file without picking up the labels and/or specify the data type of my selected variables upon the read_stata command?

The automatic inclusion of value labels is driving me isane as I had quite the opposite in R, where I couldnt seem to get the labels at all.

I would really appreciate some guidance here as I have spent a week trying to get me head around this, with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find my error - which I though to share.

I still do not know how to target only text in a column, but the error in my dara was at the read in stage.

```
w2bio = pd.read_stata(r'./Data/w2_nurse.dta',
                    columns=['idauniq', 'hscrp', 'cfib'                     
                             ])
```

converts variables to catagories because the convert_categoricals option defaults to true in read_stata, thus my solution was:

```
w2bio = pd.read_stata(r'./Data/w2_nurse.dta',
                    columns=['idauniq', 'hscrp', 'cfib'                     
                             ],
                    convert_categoricals=False)
```

in this format it brought the variables in as float, which are naturally easier to control and adjust

Comment: `df_text = df[df['A'].astype('str').str.count("\d") == 0]` is one way to identify non-numeric entries

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked with Categories much, but if you are trying to keep the float and the codes for categories separate - you could try something like this where you separate them and recombine them

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 'some text', 'other text']})
df_num = df[df['A'].astype('str').str.count("\d") > 0]
df_text = df[df['A'].astype('str').str.count("\d") == 0]
df_text['A'] = df_text['A'].astype('category')
df_text_codes = pd.DataFrame({'A': df_text['A'].cat.codes})
df_concat = pd.concat([df_num, df_text_codes], axis=0)
print(df_concat)
#     A
#0  1.1
#1  2.2
#2  3.3
#3    1
#4    0
```

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to answer my question. Although I was not to concerned with retaining the labels for the codes, your feedback was helpful as a learning tool, so I really do thank you :)